# How to add 1 day to timeuntil in django

Tags: django

I have an HTML table in which I am displaying `timeuntil` for the difference between two dates.

The code in my template looks like this:

```
Applied leave from {{pl.start_date}} to {{pl.end_date}} for {{ pl.end_date|timeuntil:pl.start_date }}
```

My `timeuntil` is showing in this way:

> Applied leave from Sept. 19, 2017 to Sept. 21, 2017 for 2 days,...

But **I need to display 3 days**. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you tried ***timesince*** instead? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

Create your own template tag, similar to what I do:

```
from dateutil import parser
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def day_difference(value, end_day):
    start_day_date = parser.parse(value)
    end_day_date = parser.parse(end_day)
    difference = start_day_date - end_day_date
    return difference.days
```

Then, try to use this excerpt in your HTML template:

```
{{ pl.start_date|day_difference:pl.end_date }}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154345/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-how-to-add-1-day-to-timeuntil-in-django). Relevant information should be [edit]ed back into this answer.